# Shuffle and deal a deck of card with constraints

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle

Here is the facts first.

> In the game of bridge there are 4
>   players named North, South, East and
>   West.
>
> All 52 cards are dealt with 13 cards
>   to each player.
>
> There is a Honour counting systems.
>   Ace=4 points, King=3 points, Queen=2
>   points and Jack=1 point.

I'm creating a "Card dealer" with constraints where for example you might say that the hand dealt to north has to have exactly 5 spades and between 13 to 16 Honour counting points, the rest of the hands are random.

How do I accomplish this without affecting the "randomness" in the best way and also having effective code?

I'm coding in C# and .Net but some idea in Pseudo code would be nice!

Comment: Is the example the only constraint? Could you explain why such constraints? Because if constraints are like "North must have.." it's really different from "One player must have.."

Comment: Without going in too much detail about the game of bridge the constraint is for a specific hand. Normally the constraints would not be to complicated where you set for all four hands. The purpose for my task here is to generate boards to practice bidding on specific hand types.

Comment: @Moron, depends on what dealer you are talking about..

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry, I meant Thomas Andrews' Deal 3.1. I believe Han Sverans (don't remember the exact name) had a dealing software called Dealer. I have added an answer, though.

Comment: The name you are looking for, M, is Hans van Staveren, and his program is called "Dealer."

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think you should just let your users upload a file of deals generated elsewhere.  The problem is that if you use a flexible language, you have to do a lot o checking to see if the code for their conditions is "safe."  If you leave an open form to the world and say, "Enter some visual basic here, which I'll run on my server," you can see the problem. :) You could, of course, implement your own language, but that will likely be limiting.

Comment: I went with just generating the deals and checking the constraints. I had to make sure there are not to many constraints as it can be a lot of deals before hitting one and I plan to run this on my hosted environment and they will close down my site for 3 hours if I use to much CPU over periods. Thanks all for the good answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how fast your computer is, it *might* be enough to do this:

- Repeat:

  - do a random deal
- Until the board meets all the constraints

As with all performance questions, the thing to do is try it and see!

*edit* I tried it and saw:

```
done 1000000 hands in 12914 ms, 4424 ok
```

This is without giving any thought to optimisation - and it produces 342 hands per second meeting your criteria of "North has 5 spades and 13-16 honour points". I don't know the details of your application but it seems to me that this might be enough.

Comment: Just posted the same idea ... It would be interesting to prevent unmeetable constraints, so your re-deal wont go to loop ...

Comment: This will really not go under the section of "effective" code. I do really looking for a way of cheating a bit.. there is 22,090,320,000 combinations to shuffle a deck and will be to heavy I think.. I plan to have this online running on my web hosting

Comment: It is "effective" as long as it behaves as desired. It might not be very "efficient", thats true, but in this case a heuristic workaround still might be your best choice.

Comment: Thanks for that update AaakashM, you might be right there is no point trying over complicate things here.

Comment: One significant optimization is to deal only "north"s hand, since it is the only one with constraints.  You can start off by dealing 5 random spades, then 8 more random cards from what's left of the deck.  Then, if the constraints aren't met, don't bother dealing to anyone else.  There are also quite likely other simple effective ways of dealing north's hand quickly in a way consistent with the constraints.

Comment: Trying to do some factory method to generate the deals actually takes too much time up front, unless the deal is very rare, especially when using the dealer to generate a handful of deals for bidding.  Also, the best factory methods are trickier to implement correctly, which leads to hidden biases if implemented wrong, while a straight-up deal loop is more likely to get correct probabilities.  Finally, a factory method for generating particular hand types is costly in memory, even when faster.

Answer (score 6):

Since somebody already mentioned my Deal 3.1, I'd like to point out some of the optimizations I made in that code.

First of all, to get the most flexibly constraints, I wanted to add a complete programming language to my dealer, so you could generate whole libraries of constraints with different types of evaluators and rules.  I used Tcl for that language, because I was already learning it for work, and, in 1994 when Deal 0.0 was released, Tcl was the easiest language to embed inside a C application.

Second, I needed the constraint language to run fairly fast.  The constraints are running deep inside the loop.  Quite a lot of code in my dealer is little optimizations with lookup tables and the like.

One of the most surprising and simple optimizations was to not deal cards to a seat until a constraint is checked on that seat.  For example, if you want north to match constraint A and south to match constraint B, and your constraint code is:

```
 match constraint A to north
 match constraint B to south
```

Then only when you get to the first line do you fill out the north hand.  If it fails, you reject the complete deal.  If it passes, next fill out the south hand and check its constraint.  If it fails, throw out the entire deal.  Otherwise, finish the deal and accept it.

I found this optimization when doing some profiling and noticing that most of the time was spent in the random number generator.

There is one fancy optimization, which can work in some instances, call "smart stacking."

```
 deal::input smartstack south balanced hcp 20 21
```

This generates a "factory" for the south hand which takes some time to build but which can then very quickly fill out the one hand to match this criteria.  Smart stacking can only be applied to one hand per deal at a time, because of conditional probability problems. [*]

Smart stacking takes a "shape class" - in this case, "balanced," a "holding evaluator", in this case, "hcp", and a range of values for the holding evaluator.  A "holding evaluator" is any evaluator which is applied to each suit and then totaled, so hcp, controls, losers, and hcp_plus_shape, etc. are all holding evalators.

For smartstacking to be effective, the holding evaluator needs to take a fairly limited set of values.  How does smart stacking work?  That might be a bit more than I have time to post here, but it's basically a huge set of tables.

One last comment: If you really only want this program for bidding practice, and not for simulations, a lot of these optimizations are probably unnecessary.  That's because the very nature of practicing makes it unworthy of the time to practice bids that are extremely rare.  So if you have a condition which only comes up once in a billion deals, you really might not want to worry about it. :)

[Edit: Add smart stacking details.]

Okay, there are exactly 8192=2^13 possible holdings in a suit.  Group them by length and honor count:

```
 Holdings(length,points) = { set of holdings with this length and honor count }
```

So

```
 Holdings(3,7) = {AK2, AK3,...,AKT,AQJ}
```

and let

```
 h(length,points) = |Holdings(length,points)|
```

Now list all shapes that match your shape condition (spades=5):

```
 5-8-0-0
 5-7-1-0
 5-7-0-1
 ...
 5-0-0-8
```

Note that the collection of all possible hand shapes has size 560, so this list is not huge.

For each shape, list the ways you can get the total honor points you are looking for by listing the honor points per suit.  For example,

```
 Shape    Points per suit
 5-4-4-0  10-3-0-0
 5-4-4-0  10-2-1-0
 5-4-4-0  10-1-2-0
 5-4-4-0  10-0-3-0
 5-4-4-0  9-4-0-0
 ...
```

Using our sets Holdings(length,points), we can compute the number of ways to get each of these rows.
For example, for the row 5-4-4-0 10-3-0-0, you'd have:

```
h(5,10)*h(4,3)*h(4,0)*h(0,0)
```

So, pick one of these rows at random, with relative probability based on the count, and then, for each suit, choose a holding at random from the correct Holdings() set.

Obviously, the wider the range of hand shapes and points, the more rows you will need to pre-compute. A little more code, you can still do this with some cards pre-determined - if you know where the ace of spades or west's whole hand or whatever.

[*] In theory, you can solve these conditional probability issues for smart stacking with multiple hands, but the solution to the problem would make it effective only for extremely rare types of deals.  That's because the number of rows in the factory's table is roughly the product of the number of rows for stacking one hand times the number of rows for stacking the other hand.  Also, the h() table has to be keyed on the number of ways of dividing the n cards amongst hand 1, hand 2, and other hands, which changes the number of values from roughly 2^13 to 3^13 possible values, which is about two orders of magnitude bigger.

Comment: Hi Thomas and thank you for a very extensive answer. I have looked at your program and it looks very nice, I'm not a TCL expert even if that is used in our production environment at work but I might "steal" a few ideas. The purpose for my software is to build a site to solve the problem for me and my partner to practice bidding, we never get the time to do it so I'm creating a .Net web app to sort of creating a correspond-bid system. I will make it nice enough for anyone else to use if they want :)

Comment: If it is running a site, you might also want to allow a person to upload a file of deals, rather than having the site generate the deals.  Then you could use any dealer software to generate deals and then upload them (given some suitable format.)

Comment: +1: For the description. btw, had you considered the mapping idea in my answer? Since random number generation is a bottleneck, reducing the number of calls from 52 (or 13) to 4-5 would be a good optimization.

Comment: Yes, but the mapping idea gets tricky with certain types of simulations such as when a particular hand is known, or you want to say "south has the spade ace and king."  You can still do a mapping, but it gets trickier.  Also, the time saved by reducing the calls to the RNG might be lost doing the large integer arithmetic - you have to do plenty of division and modulus operations on 96-bit numbers to get the deal out of the mapping number.

Comment: Like you said before, extract the North hand only when required etc (that is why I compared with 13 :-)) could reduce the computations. Also, fewer random number calls implies lesser chances of error in the resulting probability distribution. Also, these days, with 64 bit machines, these computations (two 64 bit integers) should be fast. Perhaps a clever mapping scheme can deal with stacking the hand. Of course, I am just talking, while you have actually tried it out :-)

Comment: Well, my smart stacking works essentially this way, in that it computes the probabilities of different types of hands.  Theoretically, it could count the hands and then have you choose a number from 1 to N, sure.  Remember that the smart stacking is only for one hand, not the full deal, because the conditional probabilities get exponentially more complicated.  You can have conditions on the other hands, but they aren't built with a factory.  The real problem with smart stacking and deal mapping is the complexity of the code, making verification difficult.

Answer (score 4):

Since the numbers are quite small here, you could just take the heuristic approach: Randomly deal your cards, evaluate the constraints and just deal again if they are not met.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this flow, which I think does not affect the randomness (other than by pruning solutions that do not meet constraints):

- List in your program all possible combinations of "valued" cards whose total Honour points count is between 13 and 16. Then pick randomly one of these combinations, removing the cards from a fresh deck.
- Count how many spades you already have among the valued cards, and pick randomly among the remaining spades of the deck until you meet the count.
- Now pick from the deck as much non-spades, non-valued cards as you need to complete the hand.
- Finally pick the other hands among the remaining cards.

You can write a program that generates the combinations of my first point, or simply hardcode them while accounting for color symmetries to reduce the number of lines of code :)

Comment: This algorithm won't work, because it messes up conditional probabilities.  This is roughly how my dealer's "smart stack" works, but your first step can't have each set of value cards have the same probability, because the number of ways of filling out the rest of the rest of the hand depends on the number of honor cards you already picked. The "smart stacking" feature in my dealer, mentioned earlier, does this sort of analysis, but it requires a very big table.

Comment: For example, if you are dealt five spades and N honor point, what is the expected number of honor points in your spade suit?  In fair dealing, the average spade points is simply N*5/13.  But your sampling technique would yield an average spade points of N/4.

Comment: (Ooops, expected points in spades was wrong, except when N=10, but at least in that case, your algorithm will be wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to practise bidding, I guess you will likely be having various forms of constraints (and not just 1S opening, as I guess for this current problem) coming up in the future.  Trying to come up with the optimal hand generation tailored to the constraints could be a huge time sink and not really worth the effort.

I would suggest you use rejection sampling: Generate a random deal (without any constraints) and test if it satisfies your constraints.

In order to make this feasible, I suggest you concentrate on making the random deal generation (without any constraints) as fast as you can.

To do this, map each hand to a 12byte integer (the total number of bridge hands fits in 12 bytes). Generating a random 12 byte integer can be done in just 3, 4 byte random number calls, of course since the number of hands is not *exactly* fitting in 12 bytes, you might have a bit of processing to do here, but I expect it won't be too much.

Richard Pavlicek has an excellent page (with algorithms) to map a deal to a number and back.

See here: http://www.rpbridge.net/7z68.htm

I would also suggest you look at the existing bridge hand dealing software (like [Deal 3.1](http://bridge.thomasoandrews.com/deal/), which is freely available) too. Deal 3.1 also supports doing double dummy analysis. Perhaps you could make it work for you without having to roll one of your own.

Hope that helps.